Is it possible to flash a modded BIOS for Lenovo Ideapad 110-15ACL with FN + R?
I was wondering if all blocks required to be flashed, will be flashed upon flashing modded bios with advanced options unlocked using Lenovo Ideapad 110-15ACL BIOS Recovery method?

Please focus on a single question in your post. Questions asking that we point out or recommend hardware or software are off topic here. This seems a pretty high-skill task. Are you sure that you're up to this? What BIOS enthusiasts say this and where? Do they also have answers regarding whether you're flashing all the blocks or not? Is your primary goal to try to access currently-locked BIOS options? I hope you can see that these questions indicate your post needs a great deal more information. Please EDIT your post, focusing on a single question, and adding more detail.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I'm up to the task as BIOS-MODS.com contributor has begun to assist me in this process.  I was asking ahead of time here, since you all are geniuses on here & I figured you may have the answer.  Yes sir, trying to access currently lock BIOS options.  I apologize for not providing enough information.  My main question is if Pythonic on BIOS-MODS.com can provide me with the modded BIOS, may I simply flash via the recovery method holding FN+R with the renamed filename from BIOS.cap to 1QCrisis.bin?
